# How do I convert years to months using moment.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js, momentjs

Currently my code looks like:

```
moment.duration(res.duration, "years").format("Y [years] M [months]"); //Input 0.08 outputs 0
```

When res.duration is < 0 it returns 0 only.
I tried to modify my code to

```
moment.duration(res.duration, 'months').format("M [months]"); //Input 0.08 outputs 0
```

But still doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how do perfectly convert 0.08 to 1?

Comment: What am I missing - what does `0.08` refer to?

Comment: So I am storing duration in years in my database. So if the duration calculated is 1 month then it will stored as (1/12=0.08). I am storing it to 2 decimal places. But to display it to the user I want it to be 1(not 0.08) since its more human readable.

Comment: Does `moment.duration().format()` even work for you?

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer I think that the OP is using [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plug-in that adds `format()` method to durations.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `0.08` years is **not** 1 month, it is `0.96` month, so you have to round it.

Unfortunately [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) (that I assume you are using) can only truncate duration's value passing negative integer to [`precision`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#precision) option.

#### Possible solutions:

1. Store higher precision value instead of rounding at second decimal. Here a live example using `0.08` and `0.08333333333333333`. (see [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/months/) and [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-iso-string/))

```js
var dur = moment.duration(0.08, "years");
console.log(dur.format('M [Months]'));
console.log(dur.months());
console.log(dur.toISOString());

// More decimal gives 1 month
dur = moment.duration(0.08333333333333333, "years");
console.log(dur.format('M [Months]'));
console.log(dur.months());
console.log(dur.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

2. Use moment [`humanize()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/). You can customize ouput as described in [Relative Time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/), [Relative Time Thresholds](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) and [Relative Time Rounding](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-rounding/) section of the docs.

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        M:  "1 month",
        MM: "%d months"
    }
});

var dur = moment.duration(0.08, "years");
console.log(dur.humanize());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what [`moment.duration`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) does:

> To create a duration, call moment.duration() with the length of time in milliseconds. [...] If you want to create a moment with a unit of measurement other than milliseconds, you can pass the unit of measurement as well.

So by doing this:

```
moment.duration(0.08, 'months')
```

You're creating a duration of 0.08 **months**. I think instead you want 0.08 **years**

```
 moment.duration(0.08, 'years')
```

You also cannot use `format` on a duration so do this manually:

```js
var months = Math.round(moment.duration(0.08,"years").months());
console.log(months,"month");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you really want to use `format` you can convert your duration back to a moment

```js
var dur = moment.duration(0.08,"years");
console.log(moment.utc(dur.as('milliseconds')).format('M [Months]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Things to watch out for in the above example - it rounds *up*. So a value of `0.1` gives `2 months`.